# Can't open a file in docx gem when I call it through a string

Tags: ruby, docx

I am using the docx gem to read a docx file. The code works when I write it like this:

```
require 'docx'
doc = Docx::Document.open('example.docx')
puts doc
```

It prints the doc perfectly. However, I need to get the path from the user through a gets. I need to do this:

```
require docx
puts "Provide the path of the document:"
document_path = gets.chomp.tr(" ", "") #it makes sure that any accidental whitespace is removed.
doc = Docx::Document.open(document_path)
puts doc
```

With this code I expect to get the same result that with the former one. The only difference is that I call the docx document to open through a string, not explicitly. Instead, I get this error:

```
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rubyzip-1.1.7/lib/zip/file.rb:82:in `initialize': File '/root/Documents/Projects/Wordsworth/example.docx' (Zip::Error)
 not found
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rubyzip-1.1.7/lib/zip/file.rb:96:in `new'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rubyzip-1.1.7/lib/zip/file.rb:96:in `open'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/docx-0.2.07/lib/docx/document.rb:25:in `initialize'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/docx-0.2.07/lib/docx/document.rb:50:in `new'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/docx-0.2.07/lib/docx/document.rb:50:in `open'
from test.rb:17:in `<main>'
```

I visited the docx gem github page but in the examples it gives the docx called is always explicitly written by the coder, never a string. I hope I can get some help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you allowed to access /root?

Comment: What the `docx` does internally is it just calls `::File.size?('/root/Documents/Projects/Wordsworth/example.docx')` and figures out that the file does not exist. You need to double-check your file path and try calling `::File.size?` manually.

Comment: Hi guys. I have total access to the root directory since I can open the file when I explicitly write it in the code. Also, the file definitely exists. Again, it is available when I am the one who writes in it. The problem is it won't open if it's a string. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Can I have some help, please?